# Why can't OSX detect android Galaxy S for USB debugging?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, galaxy, samsung-mobile

*I searched for similar questions on this issue but found none related to Mac OSX.*

**Situation:**
Trying to test android apps on a Galaxy S (Details below) but Mac is not detecting the device. Tried all the things below and have wondered whether this might be a driver issue (*which I've heard things about for Samsung USB debugging*).

**Questions:** 
1) Are samsung drivers required for android USB debugging? 
2) And are they available for Mac OSX?
3) Any other reasons OSX might not detect device for usb debugging?

**Things I tried:**

- **Enabled USB Debugging** @ Settings >> Applications >> Development >> USB Debugging
- **Enabled Tethering** @ Settings >> Wireless and network >> Tethering >> USB
  Tethering
- **Set Tethered mode** @ Settings >> USB connection >> Tethered mode
- **Attempt to detect devices** via ./adb devices (from platform
  tools dir)
- **Verified that "Unknown Sources" is checked** @ Settings >> Applications >> Unknown Sources
- **Verified that device is connected** to Mac
- **Restarted phone**
- **Restarted mac**
- **Added various device / product ids** to adb_usb.ini
- **Did ./android update adb** (which does adb kill-server / start-server)

**Using:**
Samsung Galaxy S (4G) with Sprint
Mac OSX 10.6.8
Eclipse Classic 3.7.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried connecting the phone using a powered USB hub? I haven't tried it yet but found this blog post that suggests it may help for Samsung Galaxy devices.

http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/

Comment: Too bad I don't have a powered USB Hub around here. Good idea though. I ended up testing on other devices.

Comment: I had this exact problem. The powered USB hub fixed it, and it costs all of $7. Only seems to be a problem on the newest iMacs.

Comment: Tried everything and finally gave up and bought a powered USB hub. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Also, try another cable.  Sometimes cables are not exactly to spec, so they work for charging but not data.  I just ran into this issue, swapped the cable, connect directly to the laptop's port.  Presto.

Answer (score 16):

Go to Tethering select and then deselct USB Tethering and you are done.
this worked like a charm.

Comment: this answer have helped me to make adb see samsung galaxy duos

Comment: Unbelievable! Selecting and deselecting USB Thethering FINALLY did the trick! I tried everything but this worked! Thanks.

Comment: Except there is no USB Tethering option on my Galaxy S3. The help file in the phone next to the tethering options specifically fails to mention OSX as one of the platforms on which USB tethering is available.

Comment: 7 years after and this still valid for S20, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

make sure that you plugin your device in the usb ports on the mac itself, not on the keyboard usb-ports.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that there is some difference between the ports, as they are marked identically on my Mac! Can debug only with two of four ports

Comment: @Bagerg keyboard ports are not powered. They are for your mouse. Nothing more.

Answer (score 7):

Well I tried all kind of stuff for a phone that was working yesterday but not today. Finally replacing the cable between the phone and my mac solved the issue.

Comment: Was the replacement cable the USB cable that came with the phone, by chance? Using the Samsung USB cable that came with the S7 worked for me.

Comment: Honestly I cannot recall which cable was problematic. I used a Kindle cable afterwards (long enough, good enough). Whenever possible I try to avoid the development on the platform as I am more familiar iOS so my memories a bit faded. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

USB driver problems happens under Windows.

For MacOS, I had nothing to do : ADB found my device.

You don't need tethering : it's for sharing an Internet connection.

**USB Debugging** is needed. Also make sure you authorize your Galaxy to use **Unknown sources** (@ Applications -> Unknown sources (it's a check box)).

Comment: Thanks Jean-Philippe! "Unknown sources" is something I haven't tried yet. Let's see if this works...

Comment: Just verified that Unknown Sources is already checked (Also updated the "Things I tried" Section of my question accordingly)...Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Does System Profiler (/Applications/Utilities/System Profiler) show the device in the USB tree? did you try a different cable ?

Comment: @superfell Great idea! I think the device DOES show up, there is this suspicious entry under USB:   Product ID: 0x2513
  Vendor ID: 0x0424  (SMSC)
  Version:  b.b3
  Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Location ID: 0xfa100000 / 2
  Current Available (mA): 500
  Current Required (mA): 2

Comment: Not sure that's it, all my samsung devices show Vendor ID: 0x04e8  (Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.)

Comment: Unknown sources was under Settings -> Security on my S-III

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Philippe. Just tick `Applications -> Unknown sources`
And `Applications -> Development -> USB debugging, and Allow mock locations`

Comment: changed port and restarted device and adb is detecting now

Answer (score 3):

This happens all the time with lots of phones. Two things that have worked for me are (1) type "adb kill-server" at the command line, or (2) try another cable.

Comment: this is quite interesting. i was trying for more than a couple of hours. now as per your answer just changed the cable and it worked.... man you are great and the pleasure now i'm feeling is beyond words... thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

This may sound crazy, but I tried every suggestion on this page except what finally worked:

**Use the Samsung USB cable that comes with the S7 (my S6 cable worked too)**

Every other USB cable I tried did not work. I don't know exactly why (USB 2 vs 3?), but that is what worked for me.

Of course, make sure USB debugging is turned on, and yada yada yada, but I did all that and still NOTHING. The moment I plugged in the USB cable that came with my S7 I got the RSA fingerprint message, and confirmed USB debugging, and the device showed up in Android Studio when I clicked Run.

HTH
--jsp

Answer (score 2):

Go to

1. Settings
2. Wireless and Networks
3. USB Utilities
4. Detach the USB cable
5. Select `Connect Storage To PC`
6. Reconnect your USB cable to your phone.

Source: [Galaxy S II Forums - Help, Mac won't recognize my galaxy S 2](http://www.galaxyforums.net/forum/galaxy-s2-help/5045-help-mac-wont-recognize-my-galaxy-s-2-a.html)

Comment: Not Useful:  
This question in Specifically for OSX.  
Windows has answers everywhere already.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me on Samsung Duos:

1. Go to `settings > More > About device(at the bottom)`
2. On that about device screen go to bottom and touch 6 times on the "Build number" (un till it doesn't display any notice)
3. Then visit again to `settings > More` and it will display developer options before the about device. Click on developer options and tweak options as you need.

Now on the mac, click on run button in android studio, it will display the connected device.

Resource: http://www.geekygadgetworld.com/3303/enable-developer-option-samsung-galaxy-grand-duos

Answer (score 1):

I spent a night fighting this problem with my `Doogee DG350`, which runs the `Chinese MTK chipset` which has issues with USB on OS X. I found the solution was to run ADB in `TCP/IP` mode and then connect wirelessly:

```
adb tcpip 5555

adb connect 192.168.1.10:5555

adb devices
```

it's actually a bonus, cos you can dispense with the USB cable and debug wirelessly. Not looking back

Answer (score 1):

None of these things worked for me.  I'm running 4.4.2 on an LG VS450PP, trying to connect to a Mac laptop running OS X 10.10.5.  Neither MTP nor PTP worked at all, even after following all the suggestions listed here and elsewhere on SO.  I only got the RSA message when I chose the Internet option from the USB settings (and then I chose Ethernet).

After that, it was golden.

Answer (score 0):

The connection via tcpip has a potential to work.  However, the port 5555 is probably not available.  I know this can work because I have an app on my Android called "Synctunes Wireless" which syncs' my itunes on my desktop wirelessly via tcpip and using port 4444.  So I used the ip address and this port showing on this app and I can see this device in my Eclipse.  Only thing is that the device type is unknown so the "OK" button is still disabled.  So this has potential to work.  Just have to find the right port number or maybe something else that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this problem and looking for a solution, what helped me is to install [Smart Switch](http://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/) app. After that my Samsung device finally showed up

Answer (score 0):

So i did some research because the same thing happened to me.
If the simple solution doesn't work you should check if you installed knox when you first launch your phone.
If you did install knox the only way for you to activate usb debugging would be to reset your phone back to factory config in order to deactivate knox (aka not installing it again), apparently you don't have the option to unistall knox on recent phones.

Answer (score -2):

I know it is ridiculous but do make sure your phone's got a SIM card!

Comment: You do if you're using the S3

Comment: No, you don't. I'm using an S3 right now in debug mode without a sim card. Android 4.3 if it makes a difference.

Comment: Well, do you even know how many sick variations of the S3 are out there? The only way I was able to get this running on the S3 I had for testing was adding the sim card. You dont need it for USB debugging per se but Android SDK would not find the device for code running no matter what.

Answer (score -3):

To activate the USB debugging on Samsung Galaxy S go to Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Development -> Check "USB debugging".

Comment: If people are posting it is because this doesn't work