# ADT in MAC OS X and Samsung Galaxy Note 3: logcat enabled. debug disabled

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, debugging, samsung-mobile

I did an app for Android and I tested it with a Samsung Galaxy Ace. Now I sent it to some friends and in case of Samsung Galaxy Note 3, it breaks. So I am trying to test it with that mobile.

I develop with a iMAC 27" with Eclipse ADT (Juno with all packages installed). Adb version 1.0.32.
The phone is: Samsung Galaxy Note 3. Android version 4.4.2 with Debugger options enabled and USB debugging enabled.

When I connect the phone, I get the RSA key. And LogCat starts to write log info. But when I try to launch the app (debug or run), the phone doesn´t apperar in the device list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I didn´t check, but one solution can be .... use powered USB connector.

You can follow this equal question:

[Why can't OSX detect android Galaxy S for USB debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606478/why-cant-osx-detect-android-galaxy-s-for-usb-debugging)